# Can i turn python assertions into warnings?

Tags: python, assertion

Assertions are pretty easy to write, but how do i continue running the assertions after the first one failed (without wrapping each one in a `try-except`)?

```py
def square(x):
    '''my sloppy implementation'''
    return 16

with something:
    '''my tests'''
    assert square(2) == 4
    assert square(4) == 16
    assert square(-5) == 25
```

Is there a simple way i can turn the failing assertions into warnings (that are just printed) instead of exceptions / errors being raised?

Comment: Not really, that's not what they're designed for. If you want to write unit tests, use a unit testing framework, e.g. the builtin `unittest`.

Comment: Assertions aren't really meant for production code, as they can be disabled at run-time. If you want a warning, use the `warnings` module.

Comment: maybe with slightly more context: it's for a student grading system... we already do this in other ways and i totally agree with you, but graders still **like** to write `asserts` cause they're a lot simpler to write... so any knowledge about a hidden switch that makes them less "raisy" and more "printy"?

Comment: Nothing easily built in, no. If it's possible at all, you'd have to dig pretty deep.